# Using PHP?= to navigate between pages

Tags: php

I am able to navigation between a php page using ID but not using project name. Can you only use an number and not characters?

Works

```
  $sql = "SELECT id, assigned, project, start, end, status
         FROM projects
         WHERE id=$id";

  <a href="project.php?id='.$row['id'].' ">'.$row['project'].'</a>
  page url: https://example.com/project.php?id=1
```

Doesn't work

```
  $sql = "SELECT id, assigned, project, start, end, status
         FROM projects
         WHERE project=$project";

  <a href="project.php?project='.$row['project'].' ">'.$row['project'].'</a>
   page url: https://example.com/project.php?project=Test
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Query parameters can be anything. All that matters is that `project.php` knows what to do with `$_GET['project']`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Note that you have mixed double quotes and single quotes in the `a` tag.

Comment: In addition to the SQL injection problems, use `htmlspecialchars()` or similar to avoid XSS attacks.

Comment: @Brad thank you that helps so much. This is a on a secure internal site. But I have been trying to find a prepared statement for fetch (select) but have not been able to find any that work, still learning PHP. I am using $connection = new mysqli.

Comment: @Reed Even if it is secure, you don't want to break your page with invalid HTML because text was injected in the context of HTML without being escaped correctly.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL uses single or double quotes for strings. Your second query puts string to a query, resulting in invalid query.

This is *not* a valid SQL query:

```sql
SELECT `name` FROM `cats` WHERE `breed` = ordinary cat
```

But this is:

```sql
SELECT `name` FROM `cats` WHERE `breed` = 'ordinary cat'
```

Of note, be careful with using any input (including query string) in your query like you did. You should use [prepared statement](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) instead to safely escape that string for your query.